# Working principle of a DC clamp-meter

Tags: electromagnetism, measurements, maxwell-equations

I am trying to understand how a DC clamp meter works and found this image:

[image]

(Source: http://www.kew-ltd.co.jp/en/support/mame/detail.php?id=60)

My first guess of how this works is that somehow Ampere's law is applied (though I am not quite sure of how the isolation of the cable affects this, because of it's permeability):

$$
\int_{\partial A} \vec{H} \,\mathrm{d} \vec{s} = \int_{A} \vec{j} \,\mathrm{d} \vec{A} = I
$$

(assuming a stationary DC current $I$).

But in the picture there is only one Hall sensor in the cap of an iron ring.

So how does the measurement principle work and how to formalize it mathematically?

Note that the wire doesn't need to be in the middle of the ring (it just have to be inside), so one cannot assume that $\vec{B}$ has the same magnitude along the ring.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic: I am looking for an answer from a physicists point of view.

Comment: Note, first, that you're applying Ampère's law incorrectly: the first integral should be the line integral of $\vec{H}$, not $\vec{B}$ because the path should be taken within the electromagnetic core, which has a high permeability.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: Thanks for your comment, I changed in my question.

Comment: BTW, I won't probably have the time for a complete answer, but I would like to point out that in accurate instruments, to avoid the inaccuracy caused by the core nonlinearity (which can be reduced with an air gap, but this increases the leakage flux), the Hall sensor is used as a null flux detector. That is, the total flux in the core and, hence, the magnetomotive force is nulled by means of a feedback coil, wounded around the core and driven by an error amplifier connected to the Hall sensor.